# Can I enable inline debugging in NetBeans like PhpStorm

Tags: debugging, netbeans, phpstorm, netbeans-8

Is there any way to enable inline debugging in NetBeans like it is in PhpStorm?

[image: PhpStorm line debugging]

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can - with XDebug, for example.  Read the documentation here: [https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html]

Comment: I read this documentation, but I can't see, how to enable inline degugging. I mean values of variable in same line like source.

Comment: Yeah they have it in intelliJ and in the Chrome browser debugging. Looks like the way to go and it fantastically helpful